# Garbage Disposal Sounds Stalled but Isn't

Tags: garbage-disposal

I installed this garbage disposal 8 years ago. Badger 3/4 HP. Worked fine until now.

The motor sounds as if it is stalled (loud hum), yet the blades turn freely (when off). I can turn them by putting my hand in the hole, or using a hex wrench at the bottom.

Are there any other possibilities besides a bad motor?

Comment: Sounds like a bad motor to me.

Comment: That is one of the places I would not be putting my hand in, watched too many movies I guess.

Comment: Try to turn it manually and connect power then it still moving. Keeps hands away, then connecting power. If it works, capacitor is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it still turns freely with the power on it's probably a bad capacitor on the motor, if it becomes immovable with the power on it's probably bad bearings in the motor.

The motor may suddenly start so don't use your hand or a hard tool to spin it when the power is on. eg: use a wooden stick.

Comment: I agree, bad starting capacitor.